# How to revert Spring Boot v2.0.1 project back to v1.3.1

Tags: spring-boot

I have managed to get my small, simple SpringBoot/Gradle REST service working with Spring Boot v2.0.1.  However, for compatibility with other projects in my group, I would like to switch to v1.3.1 [sic].  When I do that, though, I got compilation errors on the following code:

```
package com.ui.usersetting.UserSettingController;

import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(UserSettingControllerApplication.class);
    }
}
```

and if I simply comment out that code, my REST service no longer recognizes its endpoints.  Is there some way to bridge this, e.g., some v1.3.1 equivalent for `SpringBootServeletInitializer`?

Comment: please add error stack trace

Comment: There is no Java error, but rather an HTTP 404 error when my service fails to "publish" its endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SpringBoot 1.3 SpringBootServletInitializer is located in: `org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer`

update your code like this:

```
package com.ui.usersetting.UserSettingController;

import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(UserSettingControllerApplication.class);
    }
}
```